# Can any compilers recognize the optimization for this scenario?

Tags: compiler-optimization

Suppose I have a method like this (Java chosen arbitrarily, could be any similar language):

```
public Set<String> createSet() {...}
```

This method creates a set by adding Strings to it, one at a time.

Then suppose I call it here in a loop many times:

```
boolean contained = createSet().contains(someString);
```

In an ideal world, the compiler would recognize that the code could be improved by creating a separate method, `inCreatedSet(String)`, which would run exactly like `createSet()`, except that instead of putting Strings into a set, it would compare them against `someString` directly, which would eliminate set creation and end the method early as soon as `someString` is found, with no need to continue (assuming no side effects).

I know that Java compilers definitely don't do this optimization at compile time and almost definitely wouldn't recognize this in the JIT either, but are there any optimizers out there that are able to do this sort of advanced analysis of code?

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's common for compilers to be allowed to change behavior under an "as if" rule. I.e. it could, if the observable behavior of the program remains the same. The problem is then: can the compiler verify that no unintended side effects occur? Note, both in terms of the original program and in terms of the transformed program. You would need every function called along the way to provide a guarantee of what state they can/will affect. This would perhaps be declared by the programmer, or inferred through analysis. In practice few languages have that rich syntax or are verifiable enough.